# How to list all SSL/TLS certificates programmatically in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

To load the certificates in Windows I use:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("WINDOWS-ROOT"); //and WINDOWS-MY
keystore.load(null, null);
// here operations to make the list
```

in Android:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
keystore.load(null, null);
// here operations to make the list
```

How can I do that in linux? If it can't be done in Linux with this API how can I do it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them under `/etc/ssl/certs`. Simply do a `ls -l` tells you more.

```
ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/
```

They are all in `.pem` or `.crt`. Easy to read using `java.io.File` objects to read. You need a loop to read them all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace exact type o f keystore with function to get default one?

E.g.:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(null, null);
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. It opens the "jks" (java keystore) keystore that is empty. Anyways thanks for the try!